# mysql replication: show 'bad' query

Tags: mysql, replication

Is there a way to get MySQL to display the query that caused replication to stop? I have a DB with hundreds of identical tables, each of which has a trigger to update a related table. One of these is (apparently) not configured properly. I can't use the 'replication skip' trick as it will simply halt at the next write (and there are thousands).

If I can get the actual 'broken' query I can simply amend the table definition.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysqld logs to syslog where you should see the error and the problematic statements logged. Apart from that, you can call `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` on the slave and look for the "Last_Error" column to get the same information. Additionally, you could use [mysqlbinlog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html) to take a look at the slave's relay log to see if there are more similar queries in the queue.

Comment: Looks good. Had to connect to replication master and view query via mysqlbinlog.